# Grails Searchable return unique or distinct results

Tags: grails, groovy, searchable

I'm doing a search query on Grails using searchable, but I want to return only distinct results.

```
years = House.searchEvery('(house_type:"condo")', [sort: 'house_year', order: 'desc'])
```

How do I make the house_year unique/distinct, or do I need to just parse it myself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to eliminate duplicates from the results (and in this case a duplicate is considered an object that has the same `house_year` value), you can use the `unique` method Groovy adds to `Collection`

```
years = House.searchEvery('(house_type:"condo")', [sort: 'house_year', order: 'desc'])
def uniqueYears = years.unique {it.house_year}
```

Comment: This doesn't take total into account.

Answer (score 0):

obviously there is no simple way to do this with the help of the searchable plugin. after searching for your term you can filtering you result set by your own. in your case i would try to use a regular grails criteria or a hql query. e.g.

```
House.createCriteria.listDistinct {
   order("house_year", "desc")
   eq("house_type", "condo")
}
```